# Starting a task in a property setter

Tags: c#

Is there anything wrong with starting a task in property setter without locking?

```
 private someObject obj;
 public SomeObject Obj
    get { return obj; }
    set
    {
        if (value != obj)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
               UpdateToSql(value); //if object exists updates it other wise inserts it
            });
            obj = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Obj");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a very bad idea.  Any consumer of your API (that isn't yourself) would be extremely startled to find that setting `Obj` makes a server call to write the value to the database.

Comment: @KirkWoll even if its inside a Task?

Comment: That's immaterial.  The point is setters should never do heavy-lifting work of that sort.  It should be about as non-impactful as setting the value of a field.  If your code is going to go over the wire to hit a web service or a database, that should be made very clear by a properly named method such as `SaveChanges()`.

Comment: @KirkWoll thanks for the advice, feel free to leave an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting out a task explicitly inside the setter may not be a good idea, because that is unusual.

A more usual approach would be making a method for it: API users are more accustomed to methods starting tasks:

```
public void SetAndPersistObj(SomeObject value) {
    if (value != obj)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
           UpdateToSql(value); //if object exists updates it other wise inserts it
        });
        obj = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Obj");
    }
}
```

However, even this may be suboptimal, because it couples the persistence with the object implementation too much. An even better approach would be adding a listener to the property change event which you already trigger, and start the task from there:

```
ObjChanged += () => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    UpdateToSql(value);
});
```

Comment: Assuming the consumer of the class is not the one adding the listener, you have essentially the same drawback as doing it directly inside the setter.

Comment: @KirkWoll The listener needs to be added by the classes that use the class, not necessarily the end consumer of the class, but some class higher up - in the layer that uses the class with the setter.

Comment: Fair enough.  *I* would never have a database get updated via a simple property setter, but I admit it's a judgement call.